# Are there 2 distances?

Tags: word-usage, expressions

I've searched on [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/distance), [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/distance) and [Oxford](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/distance_1?q=distance).

Only Oxford says "distance" is countable.

Assume there are 3 points in a 2d Euclidean space, point A=(A,A); point  B=(B,B); point C=(C,C). Consider 2 line segments—AB and AC—is it appropriate to say:

> there are 2 distances: AB, AC

Actually this question comes from this [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3334572/697527), where point B and point C are in a group (matrix). That's why I need to use "distances" to describe point A to the group of point B and C.

Comment: It seems to me that you have answered your own question. One can measure the distance between A and B. One can measure the distance between B and C. One has measured two distances.

Comment: Cambridge says it is countable or uncountable in the first entry. While the Merriam-Webster link you provided doesn’t seem to include that information, the MW learners dictionary does: http://www.learnersdictionary.com/definition/distance

Comment: The example you have given is a little confusing and different to what is in the link. "there are 2 distances: AB, AC?" is correct grammar, I am not sure what you need regarding opposites. There are not 2 distances or There are no distances??